# Are the languages with a sound type system a sub set of strongly typed languages?

Tags: compiler-construction, language-design

Are the languages with a sound type system a sub set of strongly typed languages?

Comment: I'm afraid the title doesn't say all. It doesn't make much sense. It's like asking whether a car with a stereo is a subtype of SUV. Please explain in detail what you mean.

Comment: What is a "sound type system?" What _makes_ a type system "sound?"

Comment: @Matt: http://delivery.acm.org/10.1145/1650000/1646361/p16-wright.html?key1=1646361&key2=0931986821&coll=GUIDE&dl=GUIDE&CFID=108384857&CFTOKEN=75596631

Comment: Voting to close despite the "sound type system" has been explained by kotlinski - "strongly typed" is one of those terms that lack a proper definition (it usually boild down to "the typing discipline of my favourite language" ;) ). Perhaps you meant statically-typed?

Comment: @delnan: Good point, "strongly typed" really doesn't have a good definition.

Comment: @kotlinski: I'm not sure that I accept as universal truth what Wright (the author of the article) says about "sound" type systems (even _he_ double-quotes the term). But - a good read nonetheless.

Comment: @Matt: Agreed - the answer seems to be blowing in the wind.

Answer (score 5):

What is a sound type system? Do you consider static typing more "sound" than dynamic typing? Does weak typing imply the type system being "unsound"? Do you consider C or C++ to be weakly typed because they allow for a number of ad hoc type conversions?

Lua is weakly typed, but the types provided make for asonishing power. Soundness lies in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: Talk about answering a question with a question (or three!).  +1 anyway since it moves the discussion along.

Comment: A "sound type system" means that it is not possible to subvert the type system to make unsafe operations. C is a prime example of an unsound type system - you can easily cast 0 to a pointer and write to it. This doesn't necessary make it a better or worse language for its intended domain. But many other languages have the goal to eliminate the possibility to do such things, since it's error-prone.

Comment: Sound type system means that if the language definition determines that a value has type T, then a language implementation must enforce that the value has type T. So Ada is statically typed (type is checked at compile time) and Scheme is dynamically typed (type is checked at runtime), but both are sound because a value is guaranteed to have the type that has been identified by the type system. In C or C++, since you can cast values at will, you do not have soundness, so in this case the term weak typing is used: you can declare types but these are not always enforced.

Comment: "Soundness lies in the eye of the beholder.": No, soundness has a very precise definition (see e.g. http://eschew.wordpress.com/2009/08/31/sound-and-complete): If the type system is supposed to prevent certain situations, it should not accept programs that violate them. You can enforce this both at compile time (statically) and at runtime (dynamically).

Comment: @Giorgio: Isn't that strong typing? Never heard of it being called "sound".

Comment: @lbruder: According to this paper (http://lucacardelli.name/Papers/TypeSystems.pdf), a language is not type sound if the language definition allows "...a program to crash even though it is judged acceptable by a type checker." I have encountered this term used in the same sense in a course on programming languages I am attending. So it seems a standard term. I have to look into the relation of this term with strong typing.

Comment: @Giorgio: Interesting read. Thanks!

Comment: @lbruder: Here is some more information about type the related term "type-safety": http://cybertiggyr.com/tat/

Comment: @Giorgio I might want to adapt that definition slightly (I have citations from cornell though so bear with me haha). What about `1/0` that's `Int` divided by `Int` but you can't expect a type system (or any part of a compiler) to reject this. Your definition needs to be adjusted to "can't crash *due to type errors*, after the type system has judged it correct". Or... "A type system is sound if well-typed programs do not incur run-time type errors; that is, they do not get stuck when evaluated according to the operational semantics"... LOL