# what is an unsound cast?

Tags: language-agnostic, terminology

I have seen this term in a [few](http://okmij.org/ftp/Haskell/types.html) [places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915272/are-the-languages-with-a-sound-type-system-a-sub-set-of-strongly-typed-languages). What is an unsound cast? How does this relate to the idea of a [sound argument](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundness)? Is this a standard term?

Here are some quotes where this term is used:

- [Generic java type inference is unsound](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~sweirich/types/archive/1999-2003/msg00849.html)
- [This unsound cast can indeed lead to the Segmentation fault](http://okmij.org/ftp/Haskell/types.html#unsound-typeable).
- [we produce an unsound-cast-warning if you cast to a type parameter.](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/XTENLANG-2732)
- [compiler emitting a warning for unsound casts](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/XTENLANG-2549)

Comment: The relationship is that (an implementation of) a type system with inference is a form of theorem prover.

Comment: Also, a quotation might be rather more illuminating.

Comment: Sorry this one sounds like an opinion fest to me.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson On what basis?

Comment: Well there's been a massive edit since I commented and suggested a close. Looks like a question now, before it looked like more like a debate.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson I made the change to clarify the question based on your comment

Comment: Yes this is a standard term. [This Wikipedia stub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_soundness) explains it, if tersely. The rationale for using this term is that a type system is a kind of logical system, where formulas are assertions about (runtime) types of values expressed in the language of (static) types of variables and expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The soundness property of a programming language's type system is usually explained as:

> Well-typed programs never go wrong.

The precise meaning of “go wrong” depends on the context, but it usually ranges from “do the equivalent of raising an uncaught exception” to “do the equivalent of a segmentation fault”.

An unsound cast is a cast (explicit type conversion) that breaks the soundness property, or that can break the soundness property if used wrongly.